# How to change the accuracy of a floating point number in a cell in QTableWidget?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qtablewidget

Here is part of my code:

```
cell = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
cell.setData(QtCore.Qt.EditRole, dics[0][key])
self.data_row_selection_table.setItem(row, nmr_analysis.QT_DATA_COLUMN_ENTRIES.index(key), cell)
```

the application appears like[image]

But when I edit the cell, the number's accuracy is limited to centile:
[image]

How to change the displayed precision of the numbers as well as the limited accuracy during edit?

Comment: I wonder if my answer solves your problem or if you maybe have found a better solution? If you use the answer, why not marking it as solved and maybe upvoting it or post your own answer or discuss what is not yet good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to make your own model (derived from `QAbstractTableModel`) and then in the `data` method convert floating point numbers to the desired precision with `'{.xf}'.format(number)` or similar. This should also lift the edit restrictions.

When you retrieve the data from the model you would have to convert to numbers again.

Comment: Do not know if there is a more direct way to tell Qt that there is numeric data of a certain floating point precision present.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am sorry that I did not response for a long time. In fact I am reading a book to thoroughly study PyQt. When I was reading your answer I did not know what QAbstractTableModel is, thus I did not response immediately and I forgot this afterwards. I guess your answer could solve this problem and if I find a better one I will publish it here. Thanks again!